# Action but No Heat

Tags: hvac

Furnace (10 yrs - 2 stage)in the AM will start (motor) but no gas ignition. Pull the plug, allow the motor etc to settle down, and replug. motor starts , minute or so their is gas ignition and heat. Sometime the process is required midday. HVAC techs don't know. buy a another furnace they say. Code: 6 flashes plus 1  New ducting - no restrictions -

Comment: can you post the picture of your gas ignition?

Comment: Should be on the inside of the lower panel: what's 6 flashes mean. Failing that, what's the model number.

Comment: Yes, can you get us make/model info for your furnace?

Answer (score 1):

Get your booklet that the installer should have left and turn to the trouble shooting page. In my book, 6 flashes says to check to make sure that the combustion air inlet is not blocked or restricted in any way. Make sure that the burners are aligned properly, check the draft inducer, check the rollout limit, and to check/replace a 3A automotive fuse. Last, throw out the bum that says to replace the furnace since they do not know how to trouble shoot or fix it. That is like buying a new car because you got a flat tire.  And maybe they could sell you 2 furnaces, install one and leave the second as a spare. Just for the heck of it flush out the condensate drain trap if it hasn't been done yet. Hope this helps

Comment: Fully agree, since a power cycle clears the error it won’t be a fuse but probably is a safety switch that is sticking.